# Unable to get any result from XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am attempting to write an XSLT for an XML file I have and I am getting no results.

A simple example of my XML:

```
<Monsters>
    <Monster>
        <Name>Dracula</Name>
        <Actor>Bela Lugosi</Actor>
    </Monster>
</Monsters>
```

And a simple XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body style="background: #FFFFCC">
                <xsl:for-each select="Monsters/Monster">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name" /> 
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl>
```

The resulting display is entirely empty and I just know it's something silly that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a proper closing tag for `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: And more importantly, you don't have a proper strategy for developing, testing, and debugging your code.